# VS 2012 not responding after creating WindowsForms project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I'm getting error message! when the designer is starting to load... that's all i can provide...

[image]

Comment: Check the event viewer. You will probably find something in there.

Comment: thanks anyway, last update fixed it